# Relationships between tables from different databases

Tags: sql-server, database, relationship

Is it possible to define relationships between tables in different databases in SQL server 2008? And can you recommend an online tutorial for studying it? (I prefer ASP.NET, C#)

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, you can't have foreign keys between databases.

Data integrity is within a single database only. If you need transactional consistency across databases then you should use a single database. The main issue is backups/restores: you will end up with broken data after a restore because your backups are not consistent.

A recent blog article ["One Database or Ten?"](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2011/11/25/one-database-or-ten.aspx) explains in more details

Saying that, you can use triggers if you need this and are prepared to have broken data

Comment: Also good: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47387/best-practice-either-create-multiple-databases-or-multiple-users
It frames it as the "multiple database vs. multiple schema" argument, and one commenter mentions that "there are very few scenarios where having multiple databases on the same server is best practice".  Another says: "Oracle RDBMS has always been designed to host multiple schemas in the one database, and for different applications that is the way to go. This is one of the main differences between Oracle and (say) MS SQL Server or MySQL."

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can but NOT using FOREIGN KEYS:

1. You can use specific stored procs, which checks the consistency - in
   this case you have to make the user to use only these procedures for
   all the CRUD operations in both DBS
2. Triggers, which will check the same
3. All of the above have to run within properly isolated transaction to
   be sure, that your "just checked" values will not be deleted in a
       moment