# create table that is many to many between 2 tables in different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

So i have 2 databases. DB1 and DB2. My 'discountCode' table is in DB1 and my 'AspnetUser' table is in DB2. I want to do a many to many table in DB1 between 'discountCode' table and 'AspnetUser' table so i can se that a user already have used a specific discountcode so the user cant use it twice.

I tried doing a normal many to many table between them and it went like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiscountUser] (
[DiscountId] INT NOT NULL,
[UserId]  nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
[LanguageId] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DiscountUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DiscountId] ASC,    [UserId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountUser_Discount_DiscountId] FOREIGN KEY ([DiscountId])     REFERENCES [dbo].[DiscountCode] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountUser_AspNetUsers_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])     REFERENCES [db2].dbo.[AspNetUsers] ([id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_DiscountUser_Language] FOREIGN KEY ([LanguageId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Language] ([Id])
```

[image]

I then want to update my entity framework modeldesign so i can include this new many to many table in my c# project. So it is important that however i fix this problem i will still be able to use this many to many table like any other entity i have.

First i thought that i would put all the tables in the same database untill i asked about this problem to a friend. My friend did not have much time. All he said to me was do a join in your c# code to bring the 2 tables together. Just ask stackoverflow and they will help you how. So here i am. How do i do a join in m y c# code or is there maybe a better way to get around my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561501/2312877

Answer (score 0):

You can't have foreign keys between databases - the error is pretty clear about that. But you can still join them together in a query, you just won't get protection that having them joined by a foreign key gives (e.g. without a foreign key, you can end up with orphaned entries with no data in the foreign table).

If you can have them in a single database that would be best.